# Check if a user is near a marker in Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to check if a user is near a Marker in google maps on android. I want the markers to only be clickable if a person is standing near thr marker in real life. I was looking at using *Geofences* for this task but see that this only allows 100 fences and I have over 100 markers in my app. I could maybe restrict some of these but want to know if there is any other way to do this? And does using *Geofences* for this task make sense? Would it be heavy on power consumption etc?

Comment: You could add markers progressively by using Firebase firestore, retrieve the user gps location, and you inject the markers nearby after querying firestore, you can do your own research on that, usually I will flag this post, but at least put some efforts in producing some code

Comment: I have written code with Geofences but asked this question because I wanted to know if there was a better way to do this. Didnt want to overload the question with code because I really only want opinions.

Comment: Investigate geofire (based on firebase) - which is an implementation of Geohashing.  Geohashing is an efficient approach to "discovering" points (marker positions) based on an input coordinate.  It's not clear from question where your knowledge of markers comes from (database?) but geohashing (or geofire if using firebase) seems like a potential fit.

Comment: @Brian Just to let you know, SO is not a platform for beginners as well as asking for opinions, there is a flag option: should be closed... -> opinion-based.  Try to write in this way for the next time, I have this piece of code, when I running it, I have this issue (markers overloaded etc), so the community will be more likely to give u a helping hand